# Loop through Posted Array to output all last names

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Is there a simpler way do do this?

```
    $data = file_get_contents("dumps/datadump-hung1.json");
    $post = json_decode($data, true);

    $currentdriver1st = $post['sessionResult']['leaderBoardLines'][0]['currentDriver']['lastName'];
    $currentdriver2nd = $post['sessionResult']['leaderBoardLines'][1]['currentDriver']['lastName'];   
    $currentdriver3rd = $post['sessionResult']['leaderBoardLines'][2]['currentDriver']['lastName'];      
    echo $currentdriver1st ."<br>" . $currentdriver2nd ."<br>" . $currentdriver3rd ."<br>";
```

this echoes out what its supposed to.

```
martins
mertesacker
ricciado
```

instead of having 24 line code of pretty much the same, I've tried with `foreach` statements, but I cant wrap my head around how I pull out all 24 drivers' names (three here is just so you get the idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with `foreach` loops:

```
$data = file_get_contents("dumps/datadump-hung1.json");
$post = json_decode($data, true);

$output = '';
foreach($post['sessionResult']['leaderBoardLines'] as $userArr){
    $output .= $userArr['currentDriver'] . "<br>";
}
echo($output);
```

It seems like you might want to only output the top 3 here, which then I would recommend you use a counter within the array (or possibly just a for-loop instead of a foreach loop).

Comment: You can also use `break` to end the loop under a certain condition.